# Diacritcs in GWT regex

Tags: java, regex, gwt, diacritics

If i try to match a regex string with diacritics (something along the lines of ^[a-zA-Z0-9áàAÁÁ ]{0,100}$) it will match Báhhh on the server side (i call the same validation twice) but will fail on the client side. I already changed the enconding of the java class, but it still doesn't match.

Is there a special gwt regex class for diacritics or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, as `/^[a-zA-Z0-9áàAÁÁ ]{0,100}$/.test('Báhhh')` returns `true` for me in Chrome's JS console.

I suspect it's a Unicode issue, where `á` can be coded in several ways: U+0061 U+0301, U+0061 U+0341, or U+00E1.

Maybe try `/^(?:[a-zA-Z][\u0301\u0341]?|[áàÁÁ0-9 ]){0,100}$/`

Comment: Nope, eventhough it all works out  in the console as said, in the client side the gwt regex doesn't validate in the same manner!

Comment: Well now, it started working... I didn't really change much, i changed the enconding on the class but im sure i tried that before and it didn't make it work!

Comment: See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Troubleshooting.html#International_characters_don't_display_correctly

Answer (score 1):

Java and JavaScript regex have differences in the implementations, that may not always be clearly visible. I suggest you use different validators for each case - take a look at the class [RegExp in GWT](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html):

> There are a few small incompatibilities between the two
>   implementations. Java-specific constructs in the regular expression
>   syntax (e.g. [a-z&&[^bc]], (?<=foo), \A, \Q) work only in the pure
>   Java implementation, not the GWT implementation, and are not rejected
>   by either. Also, the Javscript-specific constructs $` and $' in the
>   replacement expression work only in the GWT implementation, not the
>   pure Java implementation, which rejects them.